# cgo(golang) : error: underfined reference to 'hello'

Tags: go, reference, undefined, cgo

I just write a very simple demo to test load the shared library with cgo(golang).the code as follow:

xxx.h

```
#pragma once
void myprint(const char *str);
```

xxx.c

```
#include "xxx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void myprint(const char *str) {
    printf("%s\n",str);
}
```

build shared library:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared xxx.c -o libxxx.so
```

ok,everything is ok from here.

now ,use the cgo load the libxxx.so,and use the **myprint** function:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
#cgo linux CFLAGS: -I../../include
#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -L../../lib/linux -lxxx
#include "xxx.h"
*/
import "C"

funct main() {
    C.myprint(C.CString("xxx"))
}
```

then, build the go demo:

```
go build test.go
```

as my title show:

```
error: undefined reference to 'myprint'
```

i ensure the path of lib/head file is right, Who can help me find the reason? thx.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths don't work in the build context, because the build happens in a different directory from your source files.

You have a few choices to provide absolute paths:

- You can use absolute paths in your source
- You can use pkg-config to provide absolute paths
- You can use the `CGO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS` environment variables
- You can use the `${SRCDIR}` variable in the `#cgo` lines in your source.

See the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) for more details

Comment: I use absolute paths in my source  or  use the `${SRCDIR}` variable in the `#cgo`  show the info :    `malformed #cgo argument`

Comment: @FreeApe: "malformed #cgo argument" is a malformed line like it says, or you're using a very old version of Go. Please update that first, and put an actual example in your question if there's still a problem.

Comment: thx, that you said is right. [https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11868](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11868)  ,and i try to test the newest version ,it works.