# cgo errors with undefined reference to

Tags: go, cgo

I have a valid C library, whose header file is located in ./src/include/lib.h.
I am using this code:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "./src/include/lib.h"
*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    C.my_function()
}
```

However, when I try running it with go run, it gives an error at compile time:

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/go-link-2251100724/000001.o: in function `_cgo_e59d248326bd_Cfunc_my_function':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:62: undefined reference to `my_function'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand what's wrong, as the library is a valid C library (**not** a CPP library) and the header file is imported with success.

Comment: (Just guessing) try buildig with `go build -x` and see what happens: maybe the source files got relocated before compiling in a way so that the relative include fails to work.

Comment: Also note that the error might not mean the header file was not located but rather that the linker was not instructed to link the library itself in.

Comment: Don't use `go run`, see if the problem is building or executing. If you need to link to something in the source tree, perhaps `SRCDIR` is what you need; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202761/cgogolang-error-underfined-reference-to-hello